# neo4j 2.0: predicate restriction on when clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This kind of query used to work in neo4j 2.m06, but in the stable 2.0 returns an error like "Argument to WHEN is not a predicate"

```
MATCH (n), (u)
WHERE id(u)=1 

RETURN 

  n.id AS id , 
  n.prop AS prop,
  CASE
    WHEN (u)-[:loves]->(n) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS loving

ORDER BY id DESC
```

how am I supposed to express this kind of conditions?

Many thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found a bug, please report it as an issue at http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Here is a workaround for you:

```
MATCH (n), (u)
WHERE id(u)=1 

RETURN 

  n.id AS id , 
  n.prop AS prop,
  CASE
    WHEN size((u)-[:loves]->(n)) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS loving

ORDER BY id DESC
```

Might be expensive though to match all nodes for `n` in your grpah.

Comment: thanks for the workaround, that was very helpful! I've reported the issue https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1818

Comment: just out of curiosity: size() works, but it's not listed in the 2.0 functions. is that supposed to be written as length() now?

Comment: I think it is new, and it was just an oversight that it was not documented. It is more or less an alias to length